# Dropdown text alignment in swift

Tags: ios, swift, drop-down-menu, text-alignment

i use pod called AssistoLab/DropDown in swift

and i want to change text Alignment for the text on it.

i tried to use

```
dropDown.textAlignment = .right
```

but this not work for me

anyone deal with this pod ?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
MyDropDown.customCellConfiguration = { (index: Index, item: String, cell: DropDownCell) -> Void in
            // Setup your custom UI components
            cell.optionLabel.textAlignment = .right
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Set `customCellConfiguration` of `DropDown`,

```
dropDown.customCellConfiguration = { (index, item, cell) in
    cell.optionLabel.textAlignment = .right
}
```